# When I register a user, there is no password field on the page

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

When I register a user, there is no password field on the page:

[image]

You see, there only Username and Email here, no password.

My Serializers.py code:

```
class UserCreateSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    """
    用户注册
    """
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'username',
            'email',
            'password',
        ]
        extra_kwargs = {
            "password":{"read_only":True}
        }
    def create(self, validated_data):
        username = validated_data["username"]
        email = validated_data["email"]
        password = validated_data["password"]
        user_obj = User(
            username = username,
            email = email,
        )
        user_obj.set_password(password)
        user_obj.save()

        return validated_data
```

My views.py code:

```
# 普通用户注册
class UserCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserCreateSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.all()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change password's extra_kwargs to write_only instead of read_only

```
extra_kwargs = {
    "password":{"write_only":True}
}
```